# How to log Magento2 interceptors (plugins)

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I want to get a list of interceptors and the order that they are dispatched. I also need to get the module name of each interceptor. I'm thinking of logging straight from the Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php class, however this doesn't seem like the best way. Is there another, better approach to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, you can use Magento2 PHPStorm plugin for this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8024?pr=

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a list of interceptors and the order that they are
>   dispatched.

`Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList; class PluginList` Provides list of plugins configured for type.

You can log (By Magento log) the Sort information as well as List of Plugins.

**Plug-in Sorting**

```
protected function _sort($itemA, $itemB)
{
    if (isset($itemA['sortOrder'])) {
        if (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
            return $itemA['sortOrder'] - $itemB['sortOrder'];
        }
        return $itemA['sortOrder'];
    } elseif (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
        return (0 - (int)$itemB['sortOrder']);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

List of Plugins by creating Magento Log

```
$this->_pluginInstances[$type][$code]
```

Hope this helps.